# Rails join two different tables resulting in data cascade to next rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to join two different tables together to get a user activity report but I'm getting wrong results and after getting the result rows I'm having trouble working with it.

Here is my query:

```
User.joins(:contract_comments).joins(:audits).where(id:1).where(contract_comments: { created_at: (dateRange) }).where(audits: { created_at: (dateRange) })
```

This produces 4 times more results than expected, for example:

```
[#<User id: nil, audit_id: 56237, contract_comment_id: 4511>,
 #<User id: nil, audit_id: 56238, contract_comment_id: 4511>,
 #<User id: nil, audit_id: 56239, contract_comment_id: 4511>,
 #<User id: nil, audit_id: 56240, contract_comment_id: 4511>]
```

This is the result after getting on a dateRange that should have only one contract_comment and no audits.

I tried different approaches to solve but this was the most promising one. But I'm stuck now and need help on how to get this report done. The reason I need the table joined is to get the first 25 rows sorted by date independent of the table it came from.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try `User.joins([:contract_comments,:audits]).where(id: 1, contract_comments: { created_at: dateRange }, audits: { created_at: dateRange } )`

Comment: Tried with with new data and seems better because its bringing the 4 audits correctly but it is discarding the one contract_comment that should bring.

Comment: Just to clarify ```User.joins([:audits]).where(id: 1, audits: { created_at: dateRange } ).count``` results in "4" and ```User.joins([:contract_comments]).where(id: 1, contract_comments: { created_at: dateRange } ).count``` results in "1", so the suggested code should return 5 but is returning 4 too.